# Is there a way to downgrade any single package in Debian?

Tags: debian

I am currently running Debian "testing", and I have just upgraded Gimp from version `2.10.8-2` to version `2.10.8-2+b1`. Sadly, it does not work for me. I can't open any image, not even create a new blank image, as it crashes every time.

Hoping that the repository would have at least a few versions of the package, I tried to downgrade with

```
apt install gimp=2.10.8-2
```

and also

```
apt-get install gimp=2.10.8-2
```

But both failed with `Version '2.10.8-2' for 'gimp' was not found`.

Is there a reliable way to downgrade any package in Debian? Perhaps some sort of "rollback" after an unsatisfactory upgrade?

I considered adding the `stable` repository and forcing the downgrade at times, possibly pinning back the offending packages. But I would like a less drastic solution first, considering that this might require too many dependencies to be downgraded. Might cause more problems than it solves.

Comment: By the way, I tried to report a bug, but `reportbug` is crashing with an uncaught `socket.timeout` exception.

Comment: Do you have the older version in `/var/cache/apt/archives`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://superuser.com/questions/459480/downgrading-packages-in-debian

Comment: Rather than going through the trouble of downgrading it, you're better off building it from source. You can get the source code here: https://download.gimp.org/mirror/pub/gimp/v2.10/

Comment: @muru Looks like I have 6 versions of that package. I could install manually! Is there any trick to help with potential dependencies?

Comment: @NasirRiley I can download and build it, but I don't know how to install it like APT does. The few times I build something from scratch I just leave it in `/opt` and call from the terminal.

Comment: If it works then what's the problem?

Comment: If the older versions of the packages are still accessible via apt, you could try `aptitude` and figure out working configuration with correct dependencies.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `apt` tools don’t support rolling back, so there’s no straightforward way to undo an upgrade. You need to identify the packages you want to downgrade, and find the corresponding binaries to give to either `apt` or `dpkg`. There are a number of approaches you can use.

The most general one is to use [snapshot.debian.org](https://snapshot.debian.org/). This contains a copy of every single package uploaded to the Debian archives, and also provides snapshot repositories with a coherent set of packages for a given timestamp. In your case, you’d look for [the appropriate version of the `gimp` source package](https://snapshot.debian.org/package/gimp/), then add the corresponding repository to your sources (see the main page for instructions).

Another approach which works in this particular instance, and which you’ve considered, is to add Debian 10 to your repositories, since the version of the `gimp` package you want to downgrade to is available there. Currently this won’t result in any downgrading apart from the `gimp` packages; you’ll only end up with `libopenexr23` alongside `libopenexr24`.

Finally, since you still have the older package in the `apt` archives (`/var/cache/apt/archives`), you can install it from there, either using `dpkg -i`, or by turning your cache into a repository:

- copy all the packages somewhere safe
- create the `Packages` file:

  ```
  dpkg-scanpackages . > Packages
  ```

  (in the directory you copied all the packages to; you’ll need `dpkg-dev` for `dpkg-scanpackages`)
- compress the `Packages` file:

  ```
  gzip < Packages > Packages.gz
  ```

  (this keeps both files)
- create the `Release` file:

  ```
  apt-ftparchive -o "APT::FTPArchive::Release::Origin=cache-repository" release . > Release
  ```

  (you’ll need `apt-utils` for `apt-ftparchive`)
- sign it:

  ```
   gpg --yes --sign --armor --clearsign --output InRelease Release
  ```

Then you can add a `deb file:/path/to/...` entry to your repositories and install packages from there. (You can skip the signing step if you tell `apt` to assume the repository is trusted.)

Comment: This worked perfectly for downgrading terminator to the last version 2.1.2-2, since 2.1.3-1 does not show the right-click context menu.