# Debian Sid: downgrading a single package to a "previous version"

Tags: debian, apt

I am happily running a state-of-art Debian Sid workstation.

Unfortunately I incurred in an "upstream regression" (network-manager-vpnc broke 1.2.7 -> 1.2.8)

I thus need to "downgrade" to a previous revision.

I am aware I should be able to do it with something like:

```
sudo apt install network-manager-vpnc=1.2.7
```

but that doesn't seem to work for Sid as I get:

```
sudo apt policy network-manager-vpnc
network-manager-vpnc:
  Installed: 1.2.8-3
  Candidate: 1.2.8-3
  Version table:
 *** 1.2.8-3 500
        500 http://deb.debian.org/debian sid/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

which means only a single version is available and thus the error is unsurprising:

```
sudo apt install network-manager-vpnc=1.2.7
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Package network-manager-vpnc is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Version '1.2.7' for 'network-manager-vpnc' was not found
```

What can I do?

**Update:** as @Stephen-Kitt correctly states "previous version" (1.2.7) was never uploaded to Debian archives so "solution" was to downgrade to 1.2.6-3.

Procedure to get to a working system (for me) was:

```
mcon@cinderella:/tmp/t$ wget http://ftp.it.debian.org/debian/pool/main/n/network-manager-vpnc/network-manager-vpnc_1.2.6-3_amd64.deb
--2022-04-28 19:34:27--  http://ftp.it.debian.org/debian/pool/main/n/network-manager-vpnc/network-manager-vpnc_1.2.6-3_amd64.deb
Resolving ftp.it.debian.org (ftp.it.debian.org)... 85.94.199.210, 2001:4b78:2000:1::1
Connecting to ftp.it.debian.org (ftp.it.debian.org)|85.94.199.210|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 125812 (123K) [application/vnd.debian.binary-package]
Saving to: ‘network-manager-vpnc_1.2.6-3_amd64.deb’

network-manager-vpnc_1.2.6-3_am 100%[====================================================>] 122.86K  --.-KB/s    in 0.05s   

2022-04-28 19:34:27 (2.29 MB/s) - ‘network-manager-vpnc_1.2.6-3_amd64.deb’ saved [125812/125812]

mcon@cinderella:/tmp/t$ wget http://ftp.it.debian.org/debian/pool/main/n/network-manager-vpnc/network-manager-vpnc-gnome_1.2.6-3_amd64.deb
--2022-04-28 19:34:56--  http://ftp.it.debian.org/debian/pool/main/n/network-manager-vpnc/network-manager-vpnc-gnome_1.2.6-3_amd64.deb
Resolving ftp.it.debian.org (ftp.it.debian.org)... 85.94.199.210, 2001:4b78:2000:1::1
Connecting to ftp.it.debian.org (ftp.it.debian.org)|85.94.199.210|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 35592 (35K) [application/vnd.debian.binary-package]
Saving to: ‘network-manager-vpnc-gnome_1.2.6-3_amd64.deb’

network-manager-vpnc-gnome_1.2. 100%[====================================================>]  34.76K  --.-KB/s    in 0.02s   

2022-04-28 19:34:56 (1.69 MB/s) - ‘network-manager-vpnc-gnome_1.2.6-3_amd64.deb’ saved [35592/35592]
mcon@cinderella:~$ sudo apt remove --purge network-manager-vpnc network-manager-vpnc-gnome 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
The following package was automatically installed and is no longer required:
  vpnc
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove it.
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  network-manager-vpnc* network-manager-vpnc-gnome*
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 2 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
After this operation, 1,026 kB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] 
(Reading database ... 244048 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing network-manager-vpnc-gnome (1.2.8-3) ...
Removing network-manager-vpnc (1.2.8-3) ...
Processing triggers for dbus (1.14.0-1) ...
mcon@cinderella:~$ sudo dpkg -i /tmp/t/network-manager-vpnc_1.2.6-3_amd64.deb 
Selecting previously unselected package network-manager-vpnc.
(Reading database ... 243969 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../network-manager-vpnc_1.2.6-3_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking network-manager-vpnc (1.2.6-3) ...
Setting up network-manager-vpnc (1.2.6-3) ...
Processing triggers for dbus (1.14.0-1) ...
mcon@cinderella:~$ sudo dpkg -i /tmp/t/network-manager-vpnc-gnome_1.2.6-3_amd64.deb 
Selecting previously unselected package network-manager-vpnc-gnome.
(Reading database ... 244039 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../network-manager-vpnc-gnome_1.2.6-3_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking network-manager-vpnc-gnome (1.2.6-3) ...
Setting up network-manager-vpnc-gnome (1.2.6-3) ...
mcon@cinderella:~$
```

Then, after checking it actually works:

```
mcon@cinderella:/tmp/t$ sudo apt-mark hold network-manager-vpnc
network-manager-vpnc set on hold.
mcon@cinderella:/tmp/t$ sudo apt-mark hold network-manager-vpnc-gnome
network-manager-vpnc-gnome set on hold.
```

MANY Thanks to @Stephen

Comment: wget rather than configuring the correct snapshot (or testing or stable...) repository prevents any signature-backed validation of the package.

Comment: @A.B: I understand, but I don't know how to use `apt` to select a specific "historic" version (i.e.: not currently considered "current" in any release) taken directly from snapshot.debian.org; info/recipes/pointers welcome.

Comment: for the repository syntax https://snapshot.debian.org/ : there are examples on the main page. For finding, find your binary package, select the version you want and go to the directory with this package: part of the URL above will show what to put as repository using the syntax on the main page.

Comment: Thanks @A.B I saw the main page, but it's unclear to me how pin a specific version (as opposed to a specific date); I assume I should be able to use `apt`'s `=` syntax to chose the specific version; could you give a complete example I could incorporate in my "Update" for the sake of future users? (Hint: you could also write a self-answered question "how to install a specific version of a package in Debian Sid" and I could link it here) TiA!

Comment: Nah, I'll let you experiment

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a way to downgrade any single package in Debian?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/539925/is-there-a-way-to-downgrade-any-single-package-in-debian)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you’re using Debian, I doubt the older version was 1.2.7, since [that was never uploaded to the archives](https://tracker.debian.org/pkg/network-manager-vpnc). Note that for `apt`’s `=` syntax, you need to specify full package versions, *e.g.* “1.2.8-3”.

Regardless, you can find all the versions of a package uploaded to the archives in the last 15 years on snapshot.debian.org; [this includes `network-manager-vpnc`](https://snapshot.debian.org/binary/network-manager-vpnc/). Download the appropriate package there, install it (using `dpkg -i`), and then put a hold on it (`apt-mark hold network-manager-vpnc`) so it doesn’t get upgraded again.

You can configure an `apt` source for a specific snapshot; see [Debian 10 : Upgrade to specific minor release (10.10)](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/688971/86440) for details. You might also find [Why do previous versions of Debian packages vanish in the package repositories? (highly relevant for version-controlled system configuration)](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/544432/86440) relevant.

Please also file a bug (`reportbug network-manager-vpnc`) so that others can be made aware of the regression and hopefully it can be fixed.

Comment: Thanks. I did not open a specific bug because I thought it was already reported; it surely was reported for [Ubuntu](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/network-manager-applet/+bug/1968588). I will search for relevant downgrade and update question to reflect solving workaround (if found).

Comment: Ah yes, thanks; I’d checked the Debian bug tracker but not Ubuntu’s.